# How can I pass variables to login and register view in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am learning and developing a project in laravel 5.3. So I stucked at a point that, to every view in this project I am passing variables to views like following.

```
public function index()
{
    $page_title = 'Page Title';

    return view('home', ['title' => $page_title]);
}
```

so in login and register controllers there are no methods to return views. And I want to pass same variables with different string values to login and registration form. so how can i do that. And secong thing I want to ask is, that how can I add a 404 error page in my project for undefined routes. and third question is that can I set 404 page to register route `(www.myproject.com/register)` after adding some users in my project. looking forword for reply..

Answer (score 11):

The methods to return the views are in traits, if you want to add you own logic for these methods you can simply override them by adding your own methods the class that uses the trait e.g.

**RegisterController**

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    $title = 'Register';

    return view('auth.register', compact('register'));
}
```

**LoginController**

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    $title = 'Login';

    return view('auth.login', compact('title'));
}
```

If you want to add a custom 404 error page then you just need to create that a file at `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` as shown in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#custom-http-error-pages

Laravel comes with a `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware that will (as the name suggests) rediect the user away from a route if they are already logged in. By default, the login and register routes already have this. If you want to change this behaviour just edit your `App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated` class.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In the login controller >  AuthenticatesUsers trait you can type your variables here.

Default path: `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    $test = 'test';
    return view('auth.login', compact('test'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Optimized** this could save your 'arss'

> LoginController.php

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    $title = 'Login';

    $css = array(
        asset('sign-up-in/css/index.css'),
    );
    $js = array(
        asset('sign-up-in/js/index.js'),
    );

    return view('auth.login', compact('title','css','js'));
}
```

Do the same for *RegisterController.php* +(bonus) every other controller
Now slay it all with this

> app.blade.php

```
@if(isset($js)) 
    @foreach($js as $key => $value)
        <script src="{{$value}}"></script>
    @endforeach
@endif

@if(isset($css)) 
    @foreach($css as $key => $value)
        <link href="{{$value}}" rel="stylesheet">
    @endforeach
@endif
```